# ArcGIS Online feature class error accessing from FME

Tags: arcgis-online, fme-form, arcgis-survey123

I have a survey123 application. I am trying to connect the feature class connected with this application in ArcGIS Online to my local database. For this I am using FME Workbench. I have previously connected ArcGIS online feature class using FME Desktop and it worked fine. This time however I am getting the following error.

```
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Could not find a Feature Service item matching the Feature Service directive
```

I am using FME 2020.1
When I added the AGOL reader and chose this feature class I am getting column names in reader which means it is able to connect to feature class, when I press the see source data on reader I can see the data as well. It gives me error when I run the FME even if I don't have any transformer and just inspector.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see from the FME community that you resolved this by changing the feature class name, and I just wanted to add this info here in case other users find this question.

It seems like you had spaces and a slash character in the name and I'm 99% certain that such characters are not allowed. You can - IIRC - create an alias for the table and that should be able to include spaces.